# Why wont whole page show responsively when on smaller screen?

Tags: html, css, sass

using bootstrap grid for responsive design, but when screen size is reduced, the footer is lost, and one can't move down page. shown below is why.html page plus styling from css file and scss file. 
my attempts to fix this have been:
to look for some syntax problem in css file, and i changed background image from body to html to no avail. any help appreciated. https://jsfiddle.net/eojcam/htkxnywL/7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon_nylon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>why</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- My styles for project0 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles_p0.css">
    <!-- My sass styles for project0 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/variable_p0.css">
</head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
                <div class="container">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="why.html">Why</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="examples.html">Examples</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <h1></h1>
                    <h2>Drop That Pick!</h2> <!-- use of unicode for emoji -->
                    <p class="header_p">It's gonna happen anyway...&#128526;</p>
        </header>
        <section class="join">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>Several years ago, after returning from a position as Orchestral Guitarist on Royal Caribbean Cruise
                            Lines ship the "Monarch of the Seas,"</p>
                        <p>I decided to take some Classical Guitar lessons with a private
                            teacher. I learned how to play the guitar without a pick...</p>
                            ...revealing some new possibilities.
                            Like playing Walking Bass Lines,
                            Chords, and Melody all at once!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="join">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Finger Style</th>
                                <th>Pick</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Thumb and Fingers work independently.</td>
                                <td>Only one attack possible.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Invented first &#128526; (technique has been developed for longer time.)</td>
                                <td>Reliance, such that if you drop it, (or don't have one),
                                    means you are "out of business!"</td>  <!--use of table -->
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
          <div class="container">
            <p id="footer_p">Copyright &copy; 2020 Joe Austin Mcintosh. All rights reserved.</p> <!-- id used -->
          </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    padding-top:5rem;
    background:url(/Users/king/proj_0/images/nylon_string_original.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #ffffff;
    {box-sizing: border-box;}
}

div {
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4  {
    color: #FFFF00;
}

h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

header {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

table {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

th {
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: #6D2E0D;
}

ul  {
    list-style: none;
}

.header_p { /* use of class*/
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:5px 5px 10px #ffffff;
    color: #FFFF00;
}

.join {
    padding:2px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.row > div {
    padding-top:5rem;
    color: #ffffff;
}

@media print {
    .screen_only {
        display: none;
    }
}

.section_d {
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: Palatino, serif;
    text-align:center;
}

#a_examples {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer_p { /* use of id  */
    font-family: cursive;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:5px 5px 10px #ffffff;
    color: #FFFF00;
}

#p_examples {
    text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {     /* media query use */
    h1::before {
        content: "Finger Style Guitar Club";
    }
}

@media (max-width: 499px) {
    h1::before {
        content: "Finger Style!";
    }
}
```

scss:

```
$cap: small-caps; /* variable use*/
    ul {
    font-variant: $cap;
    }

div {

    ul {  /* use of nesting*/

    li a {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    }
}

%style { /* inheritance use */
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.full_name {
    @extend %style;
    color: blue;
}

.age {
    @extend %style;
    color: blue;
}

.playing_style {
    @extend %style;
    color: blue;
}

.where {
    @extend %style;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: please add https://jsfiddle.net or another way to see your code in action

Answer (score 0):

the footer gets lost as you are not using the repsonsive Bootstraps design in your footer element. Also to utilise the responsive element, and grid component it is best to define an elements *col* per the device being used. For example:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-9">
            <!-- code in here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

The lg large devices, md medium devices and sm small devices. This is will allow all of your elements to adapt to a device. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/
Here is more information on the grid system bootstrap uses and how to write responsive code.

Also, to make it easier for custom styling your website you can just use one stylesheet and only link one stylesheet. Your SASS stylesheet will get changed into a .css file, you can write vanilla css in your SASS file and it will remain css.